# stumped on installation of Pi Light

Tags: password

I just installed pi light and NextCloud.

I have a broadcom 1Tb toughdrive attatched through a mains powered USB unit.

For some reason I cannot log in, it loads then asks for the username which i enter then it asks for password, which i enter, it won't accept either!

I have searched, read and tried everything to get past this but still cannot solve it, is the a way to delete everything off my Raspberry Pi 3 and start afresh?

Comment: What is 'pi light'?

Comment: Could it be "Raspbian Light"?